# copying few columns from project_1 table to temp table, but temp table return empty in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to copy few columns like date,name,description from project_1 table, to another temp table, but it creates the table with those columns, but the temp table is empty.

I am using the following code:

```
create table #tmp1
(
  Id int not null identity(1,1), 
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  Date DATETIME not null,
  descript nvarchar(256)
)   

insert into #tmp1 
SELECT Name,Date,DESCRIPT FROM project_1;
```

I checked the statement individually they execute properly, but when I run a select statement on tmp1 it doesn't show any records

Comment: Why not just select Name, Date, DESCRIPT into #tmp1 from project_1? Do you need a new ID? Just interested in your end goal here.

Comment: I need the Id for other purpose. I have to break down the description so, I am going use  by Id

Comment: If the `SELECT` statement returns records, there's no reason the temp table should be empty. Is that the full query that you're showing us?

Comment: I might have missed select * from #tmp1  but other than that it is the full query. I even executed the SELECT Name,Date,DESCRIPT FROM project_1; individually and it returns with records, but when I use select statement on #tmp1 table it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it below it works fine

```
            create table  project_1 (Name varchar(10),Date1 date ,DESCRIPT int );

            insert into  project_1 values('tuhin','2018-01-01',1);

        go

        create table #tmp1
            (
            Id int not null identity(1,1), 
            Name VARCHAR(50),
            Date DATETIME not null,
            descript nvarchar(256)
            )   ;

    go
    insert into #tmp1 
        SELECT Name,Date1,DESCRIPT FROM project_1;
go
select * from #tmp1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8287d20099d68c766054ad162ac028d)

```
Id  Name    Date                descript
1   tuhin   01/01/2018 00:00:00     1
```

Comment: Yeah even I checked using sql fiddle only to see and it works fine, but I have not idea why this is not working on sql server